# How do I configure cmake to work with rsp files when using IAR compiler

Tags: cmake, encoding, iar

When using the IAR compiler I get an error when creating a library.   This uses "iarchive.exe" in the IAR bin directory to create a library file.
The issue occurs when the number of object files exceeds the Windows10 command line limit (about 8000 bytes).

When the limit is exceeded CMake creates a ".rsp" file and the response file has a 3 bytes (Byte Order Mark) at the start of the file.

I am using a licensed version of the IAR compiler.
The tools are version 7.2.

```
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Generic)

set(CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE_TARGET_TYPE STATIC_LIBRARY)

set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR arm)

   set(IAR_INSTALL_DIR "C:/Program Files (x86)/IAR Systems/Embedded 
   Workbench 7.2")

   architectures
   set(TOOLKIT_DIR "${IAR_INSTALL_DIR}/${CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR}")

   if(UNIX)
     set(ENV{PATH} "${TOOLKIT_DIR}/bin:$ENV{PATH}")
   else()
     set(ENV{PATH} "${TOOLKIT_DIR}/bin;$ENV{PATH}")
   endif()

   Compiler and Assembler
   set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER    "icc${CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR}")
   set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER  "icc${CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR}")
   set(CMAKE_ASM_COMPILER "iasm${CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR}")

SET(CMAKE_C_USE_RESPONSE_FILE_FOR_OBJECTS 0)
```

To configure cmake

```
cmake -H.. -B. -G "Ninja Multi-Config" -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=..\iar-toolchain.cmake
```

I have also tried:

```
cmake -H.. -B. -G "NMake Makefiles" -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=..\iar-toolchain.cmake
```

Below is the error message generated during the build.

```
C:\Firmware\SRFN\build>cmake --build . --target SrfnDcu
[1/20] Linking C static library Debug\libpsp_dcu_k64f120m.a
FAILED: Debug/libpsp_dcu_k64f120m.a
cmd.exe /C "cd . && C:\PROGRA~2\IARSYS~1\EMBEDD~1.2\arm\bin\iarchive.exe Debug\libpsp_dcu_k64f120m.a --create  -f CMakeFiles\psp_dcu_k64f120m.Debug.rsp && cd ."
Fatal error[La001]: could not open file "C:\Firmware\SRFN\build\∩╗┐CMakeFiles\p
          sp_dcu_k64f120m.dir\Debug\DCU\OS\mqx\source\psp\cortex_m\compiler\iar
          \comp.c.o"
Fatal error detected, aborting.
```

```
One solution to the problem was to use a newer version of "iarchive.exe" that was in IAR Version 8.2.

Basically is seems that IAR updated "iarchive.exe" to support this.
```

Comment: Please, be more detailed when describe the problem. Provide **exact** code (CMake one, including the toolchain file), exact error message and so on. You may find useful [ask].

Comment: `exceeds some limit` Could you be more specific? What limit? What is the exact error message? Are you aware that the trial version of IAR workbench comes with a size limit? Are you using IAR workbench, if so, which version and what licensing option? `I have determined that these three bytes` How have you determined that? `how to disable this` Assuming that is true, how is file encoding related to CMake configuration? Where is the link between "building a library exceeding a limit" to "disabling file encoding"? How does removing these bytes help you solve your problem?

Comment: I am using a licensed version of iar. I have manually removed the three magic bytes from the file and the ran the iarchive command from the command line successfully. It seems that cmake builds the rsp file when the list of objects exceeds the windows limit, 8000 bytes I believe.